# Unable to pickle datetime subclass

Tags: python, datetime, pickle, python-datetime

I am trying to pickle and unpickle `datetime.datetime` subclass object. However, it always yields error and I have no clue why it is and how to solve it. Here is the minimum example:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, time 
class A(datetime):
    def __new__(cls, year = 2016, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, leap_year=False):
        return datetime.__new__(cls, year ,month, day, hour, minute)

import pickle
obj = A( month=1, day=1, hour=1, leap_year = False)
serial = pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
unpickle = pickle.loads( serial, encoding='bytes')
```

This will give the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-12195a09d83d> in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 unpickle = pickle.loads( serial, encoding='bytes')

<ipython-input-1-605483566b52> in __new__(cls, year, month, day, hour, minute, leap_year)
      2 class A(datetime):
      3     def __new__(cls, year = 2016, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0, leap_year=False):
----> 4         return datetime.__new__(cls, year ,month, day, hour, minute)
      5 

TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Does anyone know where the problem might be and how to solve it?

Comment: Always post **the whole error message** with **full traceback** please.

Comment: The `pickle` module doesn't use a class' `__new__()` method to reconstruct instances of it.

Comment: @martineau. great to know. thanks. So should I avoid using `__new__` if I want to use pickle then?

Comment: There's information on how things work in the [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) section of the `pickle` module's documentation.

Comment: The problem isn't really the use of `__new__`. (You can even see your `__new__` getting invoked in the traceback - that wouldn't happen for most classes, but it happens due to the way `datetime` customizes pickling.) The problem is that the `datetime` pickling implementation isn't designed to work with subclasses (and it's completely undocumented on top of that).

Comment: Serialization and subclassing are both way more complex than they look, but people are trained to expect both serialization and subclassing to just work without effort. Put them together, and they're even more of a problem.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, thanks. Are you suggesting that there is no way this issue can be solved unless `DateTime` changes pickling implementation, which will probably not happen at least in the short run?

Comment: No, you can override the datetime pickling implementation with your own.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, that sounds a little bit complicated than I thought. Any suggestions on where to start BTW?

Comment: The [pickle docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), particularly `__reduce_ex__`, and perhaps the [datetime `__reduce_ex__` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.1/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L6146) if you're comfortable with C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get the following to work based on the information in the [Pickling Class Instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) section of the `pickle` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances). The tuple of values returned from the `__reduce_ex__()` method that has been added will cause the `__new__()` constructor to be called when the class instance is unpickled by the `pickle.loads()` call — just like what normally happens when you call a class.

Note that I didn't need to know whether or how `datetime` customizes pickling nor understand its C implementation.

Also note that since the `leap_year` argument you had was being ignored by the implementation in your question (and it's unclear why it would need to be passed to the initializer anyway), I've replaced it with a Python `property` that computes a boolean value for it dynamically based on the current instance's year value.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pickle


class A(datetime):
    def __new__(cls, year=2016, month=1, day=1, hour=0, minute=0):
        return datetime.__new__(cls, year, month, day, hour, minute)

    def __reduce_ex__(self, protocol):
        return (type(self), (self.year, self.month, self.day, self.hour, self.minute))

    @property
    def is_leapyear(self):
        ''' Determine if specified year is leap year. '''
        year = self.year
        if year % 4 != 0:
            return False
        elif year % 100 != 0:
            return True
        elif year % 400 != 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True

obj = A(month=1, day=1, hour=1, leap_year=False)
print('calling pickle.dumps()')
serial = pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
print('calling pickle.loads()')
unpickle = pickle.loads(serial, encoding='bytes')
print('unpickled {!r}'.format(unpickle))  # -> unpickled A(2016, 1, 1, 1, 0)
print('unpickle.is_leapyear: {}'.format(unpickle.is_leapyear))  # -> True
```

Comment: Dear @martineau, Thank you very much for your help, and this is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Everything works now! Thanks!

Comment: And in regards to the `leap_year` argument: I was using it in some other implementation, and I forgot to remove it when providing the minimal example. Anyway, what you provided above also works! Thank you so much.

Comment: bilibili: I wondered why it was there. If you don't need it, just leave that part out. Anyway, I'm glad to hear you appreciated my answer (and learned how good Python's documentation actually is `;¬)`